# html5 drawImage works in firefox, not chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've just recently started dabbling in HTML5/Javascript, and am currently trying to put together a simple blackjack game. My main browser is Chrome, and I'd noticed my draw function for cards wasn't working. I simplified the code quite a bit, but the drawImage() function still didn't seem to put anything on the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 init();
});

function init(){
 setCanvas();
}

function setCanvas(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.width = 800
 canvas.height = 600
 context.fillStyle = "#004F10";
 context.fillRect(0,0,800,600);
 var back = new Image();
 back.src = "testermed.png"
 context.drawImage(back,54,83);

}
```

Now when I run this in Chrome, I get the box drawn by the context but NOT the image drawn. However when I run it in Firefox the image and box show up just fine. From what I can tell Firefox and Chrome both support HTML5 canvas equally; any ideas as to why it won't work on Chrome?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to write instead of `context.drawImage(...)` this:

```
back.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(back, 54, 83);
}
```

Comment: Could you expand the answer to explain *why* this fixes the problem please?

Comment: This fixes the problem because you are only assigning the image source. That is just a message to the browser to go and start retrieving the message. So the image is not really there with the browser when you try to draw it. What micnic has done is that he has assigned the on load handler to it, which in simple words means that invoke the drawImage only once the image has been actually restrived and is available with the browser.

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work perfectly. Thanks for the explanation too-it always helps to see **why** things work!